# What do hindus think about parbrahm or brahman/parabrahm? Why don't they directly pray to parbrahm?

Tags: vedanta, brahman

I am a Sikh by birth and also by choice, having read many scriptures.
Although I consider gurbani as my sole and soul guide, I am also pretty impressed by vedantic philosophy and upanishads, which in my understanding are very close to philosophy of Sri Guru Granth Sahib.

We Sikhs believe in Parbrahm whom we call waheguru or Akaal purakh (timeless being).
Gurbani also says that Parbrahm = Allah = Waheguru, and is known in gurbani by many adjective names like Karunakar (merciful), Deen dayal (merciful to poor), Bhagat vachhal (protector of his devotees), Raheem (merciful), Rehman, Kareem, and so on.

I also got to know that Hindu brothers also worship one god in many forms, but is it really so in practical life?

Because whenever I ask a vaishnav he says Vishnu ji is supreme most (parbrahm),
if I ask a shaiva, he says Shivji is supreme most.

But I never saw a hindu who directly worships parbrahm (via meditation on name).
Why is a deity always required? Be it Sri Ram, Sri Krishna, gods, and goddesses.

No offense intended. I am just wondering what hindu brothers think of parbrahm, because gurbani calls it the only adorable worthy of worshipping and utter dedication. And calls it alone Hari, Raam (pervading), Narayan (abode of all creatures), Nirankar, Madhava, and so on.

Comment: It is because -

> For those whose minds are attached to the unmanifested, impersonal feature of the Supreme, **advancement is very troublesome**. To make progress in that discipline is always difficult for those who are embodied. BG-12.5

Comment: Btw, I think Sikhism is very close to Advait Vedanta (or might be almost similar). This is Advait Vedantic hymn sung by your 10th Guru. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ps43KwRm6pQ&t=1245s

Comment: Yes dear, thats what I said sikhism is very close to upanishadic view . But don't the upanishads encourage mantra meditation (OM) and say idol worship is wrong . I am sure someone else has quoted passages from vedas and BG here in some other thread about idol worshippers "entering darkness". See I respect everyone and their views and their right to worship as they wish . I am just interested in knowing hindu view. thanks :)

Comment: I remember reading a beautiful verse from Mundaka Upanishad (or Mandukya, not sure) wherein it so beautifully says something like "Think of om as the bow, your jeeva as the arrow and brahman as the target. And hit the target". Meaning become one with the lord

Comment: Vaishnavas believe that Lord Krishna directly is Parabrahman. So when they worship Krishna, they really worship Parabrahman.

Comment: Brahman is one, but from the aspect or view from this universe, he has 2 aspects - Nirguna Brahman (without attributes) and Saguna Brahman or Iswara (with attributes). When we view Brahman from within maya we 'see' Saguna Brahman. Nirguna Brahman cannot be worshiped because It is beyond and cannot be perceived. We can only worship Saguna Brahman. Nirguna Brahman has no consciousness of this world. It is beyond everything, the backdrop to everything. We see the desert through a mirage; the desert serves as a backdrop only and is not aware of what is in the mirage.

Comment: यतो वाचो निवर्तन्ते अप्राप्य मनसा सह...

Comment: @brahmajijnasa how can Krishna ji be parbrahm when infact parbrahm is never born and never enters the womb either. ?? isn't god unattached to everything. how can he then have a special saguna body ?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda agreed with the sargun nirgun concept, but how can nirgun brahm be unaware of sargun brahm ?? when infact sargun is merely a projection of hidden nirgun brahm ? it is like saying 'CEO is unaware of the company' or 'the foundation is unaware of the building'

Comment: Your allegories are not correct. The CEO is Saguna. Nirguna is both the foundation and the building. If Nirguna was aware of Saguna then you are saying that Brahman is aware of duality, to be aware of attributes, Brahman is one infinite homogeneous unbroken attributeless Reality. How do you break infinity into two? The illusion does not exist to Nirguna Brahman. Saguna Brahman is only perceived from within maya, within name and form. Saguna Brahman is how we who are maya perceive Brahman. See Gaudapada's Karika Chapter IV.57-59. Also Brahma Sutras 2.1.14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What do Hindus think about Parbrahmn or Brahman?**

Brahmn is the ultimate reality or the Supreme being.

Whenever you ask a Vaishnav he says Vishnu is supreme most (Brahmn), knowingly or unknowingly they refer **Adi Narayana or Maha Vishnu**.

If you ask a Shaiva, he says Shiva is supreme most (Brahmn), here also knowingly or unknowingly they refer **Sada Siva**.

And if you ask a Shakt, he says Shakti is supreme most (Brahmn), here also knowingly or unknowingly they refer **Adi Shakti**.

From various *Puranas*:

> The Brahman is the Lord who is the origin of everything. It has neither form nor is it without form. The Brahman has no beginning; it is independent of all action. The Brahman is huge; it is everywhere. ***It has neither name nor is it without name***. The Brahman not only has no form, it is beyond all form. It had no origin, no beginning or no end.

Due to these reasons different sects have their own name for the Brahman but they refer to the same Ultimate reality by these names such as Adi Narayana, Sada Shiva and Adi Shakti.

**Why don't they directly pray to Brahmn?**

For salvation (Moksha) they directly pray to Brahmn that's what the 8th limb of Yoga is.

But for worldly desires they pray other Gods and Goddesses.

This is same as if there is an issue with Railways then sending a tweet to Minister of Railways is more appropriate than Prime Minister or President.

Comment: I think vedant relies more on "do it yourself by your own efforts" when it comes to samadhi as opposed to sikhism which relies more on grace of god. Thats one subtle difference I noticed. anyways thanks for answering :)

Comment: @Sikhandyeshallfind No, it depends on which VedAnta schools you are talking about. In Vaishnavism - Moksha is dependent on Vishnu/Krishna. In Advaita VedAnta - grace is mere lubrication in contrast of Vaishnavism where the grace is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Nirguna Brahman cannot be worshiped because It is beyond and cannot be perceived.

This I humbly submit is entirely not correct. I think the parbramhm referred to by the Sikh Gurus is the Nirguna Brahman and their teachings suggest that his abode is our true home and periodically the Nirguna Brahman manifests in human form to sheperd some marked souls back to their true home.

See this link.

http://www.santmat-thetruth.de/gurumat-sidhant-859/book_gurumat_sidhant_en_06_02_03.html

Comment: Welcome to hinduism! Kindly site references to back your view!

Comment: Dear Akshay, See the edited post now which has a link therein.